# Element with key 'surv.xgboost' not found in DictionaryLearner

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr3

I am using R version 3.6.3, mlr3 version 0.3.0 and mlr3proba version 0.1.6 (the latest development versions I could find) and xgboost version 0.90.0.2 → I am trying to use the command: `lrn("surv.xgboost")`
but I receive the error message:

```
Error: Element with key 'surv.xgboost' not found in DictionaryLearner! Did you mean 'classif.xgboost' / 'regr.xgboost'?
```

Please let me know if you would like me to provide any further details concerning the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in mlr3proba :) The xgboost learner is currently in limbo between mlr3proba and mlr3learners, as of tomorrow you can simply run

```
install.packages("mlr3learners")
library(mlr3learners)
lrn("surv.xgboost")
```

but until then please instead run

```
remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3learners#135")
library(mlr3learners)
lrn("surv.xgboost")
```

Comment: Dear RaphaelS thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately even with the temporary solution I still receive the same error. I will wait until tomorrow to try the first suggestion and will make sure to verify if it works. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hm that is strange as it works for me, but if you're happy to wait then tomorrow it will be a more stable and permanent solution anyway! Bear in mind the package is being updated on CRAN today so hopefully it will be available tomorrow but could be the day after. Please make this as answered tomorrow if it works as expected :)

Comment: I can confirm that it now works properly, thank you so much for your time. I am marking this question as answered.